# How to write a Python dictionary in pseudocode?

Tags: dictionary, pseudocode

I have a python dictionary:

```
cupcakedictionary = {'flour' : '12',  
                     'butter' : '4',  
                     'sugar' : '14',  
                     'egg' : '0.1'}
```

How would I write this in pseudo code?

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try and write it in simple, English terms.

```
01 (newDataBase) = Cupcake;
02 {
03     item1 (integer) "butter" = 4
04     item2 (integer) "sugar" = 14
05     item3 (float) "egg" = 0.1
06 }
```

Pseudo code is not a set language, it's what is used to state code in layman's terms, following a high-level language programming structure.

Comment: By the way I don't think the (integer) or (float) pieces of text would be necessary in pseudo code, I was just stating them to show which type of variable you would declare each value as.